# Notepad++ Settings Don't Save Between Sessions

Tags: notepad++

Running on Windows 10, with Notepad++ 8.4.7.

When I create a custom shortcut in Settings > Shortcut Mapper, it works for the current session I have open. If I save my file, close the program, and reopen the program the shortcut no longer works, and it is not saved when I check the Shortcut Mapper.

Similarly, settings I configure in Settings > Preferences > Auto-Completion also do not save between sessions. I have to always enable settings that I want in the auto-completion menu every time I re-open Notepad++.

I'd like my settings and shortcuts to be saved between sessions. I'm trying to have Word Wrap be default, but that doesn't seem to be possible. So, I assigned a shortcut to it, but that doesn't save either.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated. I searched through some other similar questions, but could not find anything other than trying to run Notepad++ as an administrator, which I've also tried and no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program as Administrator and see if settings are correctly saved.

If so, common reasons for that behavior are:

- The app was installed by Admin and is being used by another user.

  *Fix:* Uninstall as Admin, reinstall as user.
- The app was set up for *portable* use, storing its settings within the app folder, **but** the app folder is in *Program Files* or *Program Files (x86)*, which restricts writing the settings data on app close.

  *Fixes:*

  - Move app to another folder, e.g., into *ProgramData*.
  - Change permissions on existing folder to allow user to write data.
  - Remove app and install, rather than use as portable version.